# Post Service is called but doesn't post

Tags: java, servlets

Its my first time writing servlets. I successfully post via ajax (It gives the Output Service called). However, I realized that it doesnt post anything in my database. It also doesnt give any errors.

Anyone knows what I do wrong?

Here is my script:

```
@POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createBestellung(
            @FormParam("Uhrid") int uhrid,
            int id
            ) {
        Bestellung entity = new Bestellung();
        ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = null;
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT max(id) FROM Kunde";

            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.conn.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();


            if (rs.next() == false) 
                throw new SQLException("No result found for id=" + id);


            entity.setId(rs.getInt(2));

            UhrDao uhrDao = new UhrDao(this.conn);
            Uhr uhr = uhrDao.loadById(rs.getInt(1));
            entity.setUhr(uhr);

            KundeDao kundeDao = new KundeDao(this.conn);
            Kunde kunde = kundeDao.loadById(rs.getInt(2));
            entity.setKunde(kunde);

            conn = DbConnection.getInstance();

            BestellungDao dao = new BestellungDao(conn);

            entity = dao.insert(entity);

            System.out.println("Inserted entity: " + entity.toString());

            responseBuilder = Response.status(Status.OK).entity(entity);

        } catch (DbException | SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            ServiceException se = new ServiceException("Fehler aufgetreten", e);
            responseBuilder = Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(se.toJSON());
        } finally {

            conn.close();
        }

        // return the response
        return responseBuilder.build();
}
```

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'rest/Bestellung',
                method: 'POST',
                data: $("#uhrid").serialize(),
                dataType: 'JSON'
            }).done(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                // erfolgsfall
                alert("klappt")
                // 
            }).fail(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
                alert("fehler")
                // fehlerfall
            });
            });
```

Output:
Service called
but nothing else happens

I hope someone can help me to fix my problem

Comment: from where did you got `id` value , i didn’t saw that in your `servlet` code

Comment: i forgot to change the sql code sorry. but still doesn't work .New code is edited.

Comment: In above code you don't need this line `preparedStatement.setInt(2, id);` , also does this ->`BestellungService - createBestellung` get printed in your `ajax-reponse`

Comment: edited. How can i set my ID as the value of the sql string? i guess thats my problem

Comment: You need to select values from table where your id matches with the id comes from ajax , if this the case simple write query i.e :`SELECT * FROM Kunde where id = ? ` and set id for it by writing : `preparedStatement.setInt(1,id);` , also try to check if `id` have some value in it or not .